How to do rarefaction curves in R from Phyloseq object?
Just to preface, I am very new to coding. I managed to load my taxonomy, OTU and metadata into Phyloseq object. I am trying to do rarefaction curves using vegan and this is the code and error message:

rare_curve <- rarecurve(otu_table(physeq), step = 1000)
Error in as(x, "matrix")[i, j, drop = FALSE] :
(subscript) logical subscript too long

Perhaps it is problem with my input file?
my OTU table
I tried to run separate to phyloseq OTU table but still it's not working.
